# What software to handle a PS2 disk (create/delete/extend/move partitions)?

Tags: ps2, hard-drive, homebrew

I was wondering what free tools were available to format an hard disk to be readable by a PS2, create and manage partitions, extend, rename them.

Answer (score 1):

From a PS2 directly you can use the `HDD Manager` inside the `LaunchELF` (`Misc` section) file manager included with [FMCB](https://github.com/TnA-Plastic/FreeMcBoot)